# Installing windows 8.1 Pro "Full Version"" when windows 8 is already installed

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

I built a PC with a "refurbished" motherboard. I went to install windows 8.1 pro "full" on the system, and it didn't ask for an activation key, which has never happened.  After it was done installing I thought that was odd so checked to see if it was activated, only to see that it was, just not with the "pro" version. So I tried erasing the drive and re-installing with a windows 8 pro "system builder" DVD, but the same thing happened.

I have also tried "get more features with a new addition of windows" using multiple windows 8 pro keys, but it says they are no good. I assume because there not upgrade versions but system builder editions.

I assume the mobo is still registered with windows 8 because I have managed to extract a windows 8 key using belarc.

I need this PC to accept the windows 8 pro version that I am trying to install.

Any ideas if I am missing something or a way to get this done?

Comment: **All versions of Windows 8.1 are the full version.**  There is no other type of license except for the **System Builder** license.  So my guess the **Windows 8.1** license is not actually a key to Windows 8.1 Professional.  Does the disk actually say **Windows 8.1 Professional** on it?  You cannot instal Windows 8.1 with a Windows 8 license, so you being unable to do so, is to be expected.  If you want to activate a Windows 8.1 installation with a Windows 8.0 license that requires using a generic **Windows 8.1** license then changing the license AFTER its installed to the **Windows 8.0** key

Comment: How you do this is well documented on this website.  There already exists a question with an answer I myself provided that explains the process.

Comment: Yeah the one CD I was trying says "windows 8.1 pro full version" and the other is a windows 8 pro system builder. I'll try re-installing with the windows 8 pro disk and see if it will let me upgrade to pro via windows then that way. If that doesn't work would removing the cmos battery unregister the windows that is locked on the system?

Comment: Are these disks straight from MS, or are they burned by someone?  If they are burns, are you sure they're labelled correctly?

Comment: They came sealed in the Microsoft envelope and I have 3 windows 8 pro CD's and 1 windows 8.1 pro CD and they all look authentic. It doesn't matter what I put in it just assumes the windows 8 standard since it's registered to the mobo I assume

Comment: I also tried reformatting and installing using the windows 8 pro CD, then using the key via "get more features with a new addition of windows". Still failed. Is it even possible to use a system builder windows 8 pro key to upgrade a windows 8 standard or do I need to try a different approach?

Comment: Wait.  You said nothing about Windows 8.0 Core being installed; no; you can't use a system builder license to upgrade a core edition of windows 8 or 8.1; you will have to build your own wim image with the key already assigned because your dealing with OEM hardware.

Comment: So your saying the MSI x79a-GD45 Plus Mobo (not a dell, hp, etc) that I bought refurbished for a build, could still have a windows 8 standard key permanently locked on it? But thanks I will look into building a wim image tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far this solution has worked.
 I got a generic windows 8.1 pro "upgrade key" (a key meant to upgrade from 8.1 standard to pro).

I opened "get more features with a new addition of windows" and used this key. It worked and was now recognized as a windows 8.1 pro machine.

I then opened "change product key" in system settings, used the system builder key I had, and activated it via phone, and all is good so far.